# Reflection Setting values of a class

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to build an extension to populate an object with values from a SQLDataReader.

The code I have so far is

```
public static T RetunObject<T>(this Type source, SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        Type type = source.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            property.SetValue(property, dr[property.Name]);
            type.GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(type, dr[property.Name]);
        }

        return type.Cast<T>();
    }
```

One thing for sure is the last line is not right and not exactly sure if there is a way for this to work at this point.

The goal results would be to use the code like

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
var results = myclass.ReturnObject(myDataReader);
```

Reflection has never been my strong suit. so I am pretty sure I am pretty far off.

**UPDATED CODE WHICH APPEARS TO WORK**

```
    public static object RetunObject(this object source, SqlDataReader dr)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in source.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
            {
                if(dr.GetSchemaTable().Select("ColumnName='"+ property.Name+"'").Count() == 1)
                {
                    var readervalue = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal(property.Name));
                    property.SetValue(source, readervalue);
                }
            }
        }
        return source;
    }
```

it is used like

```
     return (Role)role.RetunObject(sqlcomm.ExecuteReader());
```

Takes a SQLDataReader and returns an generic object which is able to be cast to the object type you need it to be. Obviously if you try to cast to an invalid type of object then it won't work but so far this seems to work. My next trial will be to test nested class to see if it will work there as well.

Comment: What is `source` meant to represent? Where are you actually creating a new object of type `T`? This is pretty close, but you're trying to set property values on an object representing the *type* of the object, rather than the object itself.

Comment: source is representing "myclass" shown in var results = myclass.ReturnObject(myDataReader);

You're on target of what I am trying to do, do you have suggestions on how to fix it

Comment: eocron's answer is identical to what I would have told you; he just submitted his first, and also made the wise suggestion of considering EF.

Comment: EF has always caused me issues in the past when data structures have to be changed. I stay away from EF altogether.

Comment: I thought it was just me! A lot of people seem to like it though.

Answer (score 1):

In your example there is plenty errors and it is completely unclear what you try to accomplish. Probably you tried to just apply properties from reader to your object:

```
public static T RetunObject<T>(this T source, SqlDataReader dr)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        property.SetValue(source, dr[property.Name]);
    }
    return source;
}
```

But, I recommend you to use Entity Framework for this, because you probably creating another bicycle by doing this. This task was completed a lot better/faster/safer than the solution you try to accomplish.

Try to spend a little of your time on things people commonly use before trying to implement something, that no one beside you will understand/support.

It will be a lot more useful and faster than spending time on potentially buggy code. Here is good start in EF Code First: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: He should also be checking to make sure the columns corresponding to the properties actually exist in the data reader.

Comment: My classes are made from the structure of database tables so the fields would be the same.

Comment: the goal of this is to prevent having to write a lot of repeated code, the hope was to pass the object type, read the field names and pull the data from the data reader setting the values to the object fields. Seeing as how I would be reusing this for multiple different object types specifying the object type would defeat the purpose

Comment: Just try to read carefully about EF. The problem you described is solved long ago.